# Datastore ID Google appengine using negative integer, specifically -1

Tags: google-app-engine

There seems to be a problem with an id of -1 for my application.  The application
was using this ID for several months without a problem.  (I have a generation
integer that goes from zero to infinity--I map the zero to -1 since Google
Appengine does not accept ID of zero.)

The program below simply creates a new entity
stores it, and then tries to retrieve it.

The log messages say:

```
TE doGet: finished putting item
TE doGet: debug Entity Failed on -1|Key|generation(-1)|
```

The datastore viewer shows me two entities of type "GEN"
One is id=1 and the other is id=10001.
When I click on the "id=1", it shows me

Decoded entity key: gen: id=-1 > GEN ID=1

Both id's are links.  When I click on the "id=-1", it says

This entity doesn't exist.

When I click on "GEN: id=1" It gets me the information I dropped in with
the program.

-- imports and suppress warnings removed to save space

```
public class TE extends HttpServlet{

    private ExperimentUtil eUtil = new ExperimentUtil();

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                   StatusServlet.class.getName());
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
               throws IOException {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

long DMyGen = -1;
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("gen",-1);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
Entity a;
a = new Entity("GEN",k);
datastore.put(a);
log.info("finished putting item");
out.println("finished putting item");
k = KeyFactory.createKey("generation",DMyGen);
try {
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity e = datastore.get(k);
log.info("debug entity get succeeded");
out.println("debug entity get succeeded");
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
  log.severe ("debug Entity Failed on "+DMyGen + "|Key|"+k+"|");
}
out.println ("TE finished!");
return;

}
}
```

Thank you for your kind and erudite comments on this query.  Many of you asked
why one would use a negative ID.  That certainly is a reasonable question.
My participatory democracy application numbers the generations of budget
proposals from zero to N.  Google appengine does not accept ID's of zero.
Thus, I put in a mapping function that mapped zero to -1 and left other id's
alone.  This I have changed to simply add one.

The application is working better.  I ran a new test.  Here are the new
version of the two 
programs.  Both completed successfully as indicated by that which appears
on browser.

However, I see strange results on the Datastore viewer
edit Entity: Gen

```
Decoded entity key: gen: id=4 > GHen: id=10001
```

(I also ran this with DMyGen = 4 as well as 
s five.)

-- again import statements redacted to save space

```
public class TE extends HttpServlet{

    private ExperimentUtil eUtil = new ExperimentUtil();

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StatusServlet.class.getName());
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

long DMyGen = 5;
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("gen",DMyGen);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
Entity a;
a = new Entity("GEN",k);
datastore.put(a);
log.info("finished putting item");
out.println("finished putting item");
k = KeyFactory.createKey("gen",DMyGen);
try {
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity e = datastore.get(k);
log.info("debug entity get succeeded");
out.println("debug entity get succeeded");
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
  log.severe ("debug Entity Failed on "+DMyGen + "|Key|"+k+"|");
}
```

---****--second test to see if the GEN

```
public class Te extends HttpServlet{

    private ExperimentUtil eUtil = new ExperimentUtil();

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StatusServlet.class.getName());
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Key k;
long DMyGen = 5;
k = KeyFactory.createKey("gen",DMyGen);
PrintWriter out;
out = resp.getWriter();
try {
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity e = datastore.get(k);
log.info("debug entity get succeeded"+e);
out.println("debug entity get succeeded");
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
  log.severe ("debug Entity Failed on "+DMyGen + "|Key|"+k+"|");
}
```

Comment: yeah, I remember I was unable to save entity with a negative id

Comment: This is more of a bug report than a request for help isn't it? I'm just curious: Why did you use negative identifiers in the first place?

Comment: In my case it was 3rd party ids, used for reference, and I just stored them as strings. And I have same question to author of this 3rd party system :)

Comment: Note--I updated the document to reflect those changes I made on the basis of this discussion and my current issue.